# Getting version of .Net AWS SDK

Tags: c#, .net, aws-sdk

I am writing an application that uses the AWS SDK within .NET, I would like to be able to display the version number of the AWS SDK being used.  So far I have found how to get this information for Java version of the SDK but similar methods don't seem to exist for the .NET version.

Is there a way I can programmatically get this information?

Comment: The same way you'd get the version of any other assembly? See [How can I get the assembly file version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909555).

Comment: @mason Cheers, as there are multiple assemblies in the SDK I guess no one is a better choice than any other?