# Is there a way to add the assembly version to the app.config file version increments are added to the config on build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want the config file to show the app version of my c# application.
The app version is auto incremented.
Is there a way I can add it to the app.config, maybe pre-build?

I saw that c# has a pre build option for the project, but Im not sure how this would work.

Comment: Sounds like an x/y problem, why does the version need to be in your config file? You can read the version information from an assembly

Comment: @Rohit, you can read [How can I get the assembly file version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909555/how-can-i-get-the-assembly-file-version) to know how to get the assembly version correctly. Then, what do you mean that 'The app version is auto incremented'? When do they increment?