# How do I set the ProductVersion in .Net6.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I retrieve the product version as follows

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fvi = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
```

But where do I set it?

I have tried looking at the project properties and can find AssemblyVersion but not ProductVersion

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The property is PackageVersion

Which shows in the project file as

```
<Version>1.0</Version>
```

Comment: This question is related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909555/how-can-i-get-the-assembly-file-version?rq=1