How to change how CommandlineParser reports --version
I'm using https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline in my C# console application. The built-in --version switch reports the version that is the assembly version (Product Version in the assembly file's details property tab). Is there a quick and easy way I can make the --version switch report the File Version for the assembly?

The info is provided by the AssemblyInformationalVersion, not the assembly version. When that doesn't exist, the assembly version is used. Even the AssemblyFileVersion attribute defaults to the assembly version if no value is specified.

why do you even want that? What do you actually want to achieve with this?

@MakePeaceGreatAgain the File Version contains the build number whereas the Product Version doesn't, for example, the latter is 2.0 and the former is 2.0.5.0, but the build number is more useful for support purposes. I don't have control over the version number usage.

I know. However why do you use the --version-switch, instead of any of the fiunctions defined in the Assembly-class? Se this question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909555/how-can-i-get-the-assembly-file-version
